# MS SQL Server data consolidation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

At the office we need to consolidate a MS SQL table, we should get 1 line per Quotaion number.
See Table: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8AuHxQASEWyaEhfSVpDT3lIV1U/view?usp=sharing

Tried using `SELECT DISTINCT` but can't get it.

SQL Server query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ([QuotationNumber])
      ,[CreationDate]
      ,[QuotationDate]
      ,[CustomerNumber]
      ,[CustomerName]
      ,[SalesPersonName]
      ,[Rreg]
      ,[ProductDescription]
      ,[FamilyDescription]
      ,[NameVariant]
      ,[StringValue]
FROM [ABC].[dbo].[DEF]
WHERE [CreationDate] > "2017-05-08 00:00:00.000"
ORDER BY [CreationDate] DESC
```

Comment: of course DISTINCT doesn't help you, as the columns FamilyDescription, NameVariant and StringValue differ between the records.

what are you going to approach? why don't you split your table in two tables? you should normalize the data

Comment: Just change the Account in to Quotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep all the column, you can't. Either you remove [FamilyDescription], [NameVariant], [StringValue] from your `select` or you add new columns for those values in your destination result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ([QuotationNumber])
      ,[CreationDate]
      ,[QuotationDate]
      ,[CustomerNumber]
      ,[CustomerName]
      ,[SalesPersonName]
      ,[Rreg]
      ,[ProductDescription]
FROM [ABC].[dbo].[DEF]
WHERE [CreationDate] > "2017-05-08 00:00:00.000"
ORDER BY [CreationDate] DESC
```

There is what you should do to keep all values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [QuotationNumber]
      ,[CreationDate]
      ,[QuotationDate]
      ,[CustomerNumber]
      ,[CustomerName]
      ,[SalesPersonName]
      ,[Rreg]
      ,[ProductDescription]
      ,MIN([FamilyDescription]) [FamilyDescription]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NameVariant = 'DT_residual' THEN StringValue END) [DT_residual]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NameVariant = 'DT_interestRateSum' THEN StringValue END) [DT_interestRateSum]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN NameVariant = 'DT_depositValue' THEN StringValue END) [DT_depositValue]
FROM [ABC].[dbo].[DEF]
GROUP BY [QuotationNumber]
      ,[CreationDate]
      ,[QuotationDate]
      ,[CustomerNumber]
      ,[CustomerName]
      ,[SalesPersonName]
      ,[Rreg]
      ,[ProductDescription]
HAVING [CreationDate] > "2017-05-08 00:00:00.000"
ORDER BY [CreationDate] DESC
```

Comment: Ok, do you mean we will need to split the table in x differents lines with `[QuotationNumber]` as reference?

Comment: Really depend on what you are trying to do. If you only want a list, you can have it with the query I updated in my answer

Comment: This is what we are trying to get:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8AuHxQASEWySVlsd2xCRGVhcVU/view?usp=sharing